# C - open/read putting trash

Tags: c

I'm doing a simple C version of cat.

everything works but its appending some trash when I'm doing the prinf.

what/why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fp;
    int i,n;
    char ch;
    int f;
    char buffer[1024];

    //nao foi especificado nenhum ficheiro
     if(argc<2){
            printf("usar mycat <ficheiro> \n");
            return 0;
     }

      for(i=1; i<argc;i++){
        //fp = fopen(argv[i],"r");
        f = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
        //Nao existe ficheiro
        //if(f == NULL) {
        if(f == -1) {
         printf("%s: Nao existe esse ficheiro\n", argv[i]);
            return 0;
            }

        /*
        while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
         putchar(ch);
            }
        */
         while((n=read(f,buffer,1024)) > 0) {
            printf("%s",buffer);
        }
        //fclose(f);
         close(f); 

      }

    return 1;
}
```

ignore the fopen code that is commented.

Comment: Please understand what the [mcve](/help/mcve) means - it means that you will need to remove all that unnecessary code and comments before posting your question. As for the error, the `read` returns a string that is not 0-terminated, so you cannot use it with `printf("%s")`; replace your printf with `write(1, buffer, n);` for example.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that 1 is stdout? other option should be adding and \0 to the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer from `read` is not null-terminated, and it cannot be printed with `printf("%s", buffer)` because behaviour is undefined when the string corresponding to  `%s` is not null-terminated.

One option is to have a buffer of 1024 + 1 characters:

```
char buffer[1024 + 1];
```

then read 1024 characters into it

```
n = read(f, buffer, 1024)
```

and zero-terminate it:

```
buffer[n] = 0;
```

---

But the Unix tools often handle null characters in input, and in this case there is little reason to not to, so you can use `fwrite` or `write` to write those n bytes, for example

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, n, stdout);
```

or

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, n);
```